# Not getting XFS Events[Windows Messages] (SERVICE_EVENTS, EXECUTE_EVENTS) in my application after registering using WFSRegister

Tags: c#, c, dll, cen-xfs

I have a C# console application where I'm using CEN XFS(Extensions for Financial Services) specification to get ATM information. I'm using PInvoke to communicate with msxfs.dll. I'm registering to listen for SERVICE_EVENTS, USER_EVENTS, SYSTEM_EVENTS, EXECUTE_EVENTS invoking method

```
HRESULT WFSRegister(hService, dwEventClass, hWndReg)
```

In my code I create an instance of WNDCLASSEX assign a method that will process Windows Messages to its lpfnWndProc field; then I register a class using RegisterClassEx([In] ref WNDCLASSEX lpWndClass) and create a Window calling CreateWindowEx.

In my code later I execute WFS_CMD_CDM_SET_CASH_UNIT_INFO command and it returns WFS_SUCCESS, base on the documentation this command will generate WFS_SRVE_CDM_CASHUNITINFOCHANGED service event but I'm not getting any window message with value 304 (#define WFS_SRVE_CDM_CASHUNITINFOCHANGED (CDM_SERVICE_OFFSET + 4)) or any message related with XFS Events.

It is possible that the msxfs.dll or Service Providers I'm using does not have events notification implemented.
Am I missing something that prevents me to get windows messages?

Comment: In WndProc in C (sorry but I don't know about C#) you receive a WFS_SERVICE_EVENT message, not a WFS_SRVE_CDM_CASHUNITINFOCHANGED. You need to cast lParam to a LPWFSRESULT pointer and get u.dwEventID. This EventID will be equal to WFS_SRVE_CDM_CASHUNITINFOCHANGED. You only need to register as you do and it should be work, so I think the problem is in your window, not in msxfs. Can you try with another event? Not all vendors, versions and machines support all XFS specification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not getting message = 1045 (WM_USER + 21). Probably what is happening is that services in machine I'm using does not implement(trigger) XFS Events(XFS Service Events).

Comment: If these services providers you are using are of one known vendor (NCR, Wincor-Nixdorf, Diebold, OKI, GRG,... comercial vendors), the events should work and you only need to register to receive it.

Comment: Have you being able to get events(specifically SERVICE_EVENTS and EXECUTE_EVENTS)
in your apps using WFSRegister function of msxfs.dll? I believe Service Provider is generating messages
but somehow they are not being broadcasted to Window I've created.

Comment: Yes, in all apps and with all Service Providers. But, I always develop app in C. It is easy: The Service Provider executes PostMessage Windows API and send the Windows Message to the Window handle received in WFSRegister. Events like Hardware Error, Cash Unit info Changed, Items Taken, Card Taken. It works, allways. So review the process to manage your Window.

Comment: Actually the application is sometimes made in Java, but there is always a wrapper in C (in a dll), which negotiates with msxfs and facilitates the interface with Java. You could still do something similar. Include the event reception window and general access to msxfs in a dll in C and implement an easier interface for your C # part

Comment: Thank you for your help, I use the async version WFSAsyncRegister and  was able to get messages in WndProc. Other problem I had was not creating the Form where I override WndProc method in a separate thread. Because I was using a Console Application I needed to create a thread and call Application.Run(FormInstanceHere), this will create a message loop and will get Messages.

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive window messages you must have a separate thread which is running the equivalent of the standard Windows message pump:

```
    MSG     msg = { 0 };
    BOOL    bRet;

    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0)) != 0) { 
    if (bRet == -1) {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    } else {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

Furthermore, it is not necessary to do all this via P/Invoke — you can do it in C# natively by creating a hidden form and overriding `WndProc`. You still have to create and run that form on a separate thread, and to use `Invoke` when you need to close it.

Note that for the form to be fully hidden in addition to setting the `FormBorderStyle` to `None`, `ShowIcon` to `false`, `ShownInTaskbar` to false, `Visible` to `false`, and `WindowState` to `Minimized`, you should also change the [Extended Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) to include `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` during form creation:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        var Params = base.CreateParams;
        Params.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
        return Params;
    }
}
```

Finally, note that the `WFSRESULT` pointer which you get via `lParam` in `WndProc` when you receive an event needs to be freed using `WFSFreeResult()`. Inspecting the `Buffer` member of the `WFSRESULT` structure and marshaling any nested structures returned in it needs to be completed before calling `WFSFreeResult()` or the data will be invalid.